# Unique pair of positive integers $(p,n)$ satisfying $p^3-p=n^7-n^3$ where $p$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, diophantine-equations

> **Q.** Find all pairs $(p,n)$ of positive integers where $p$ is prime and $p^3-p=n^7-n^3$.

Rewriting the given equation as $p(p+1)(p-1)=n^3(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$, we see that $p$ must divide one of the factors $n,n+1,n-1,n^2+1$ on the $\text{r.h.s}$.

Now, the $\text{l.h.s}$ is an increasing function of $p$ for $p\ge1$. This implies that for any given $n\ge1$, there is exactly one real $p$ for which $\text{l.h.s}=\text{r.h.s}$. For $p=n^2$, we get $\text{l.h.s}=n^6-n^2<n^7-n^3=\text{r.h.s}.$ This means that either $p>n^2$ or $p<n^2$ must hold.

Assuming $p>n^2$, it follows that the prime $p$ cannot divide any of $n,n+1,n-1$. So $p$ must divide $n^2+1$ and hence $p=n^2+1\quad (\because p>n^2)$.

Substituting the value of $p$ in the given equation we get, $n^2+2=n^3-n\implies n^3-n^2-n=2$. As the factor $n$ on the $\text{l.h.s}$ must divide $2$, the above equation has a unique integer solution $n=2$.

Finally, we get $(5,2)$ as the solution to the given equation.

> But how do I conclude this is the only solution possible? Also, why does'nt $p<n^2$ (the case which I ignored) hold? As a bonus question, I would like to ask for any alternative/elegant solution (possibly using congruence relations) to the problem.

Comment: You said LHS is an increasing function, and at $p=n^2$ LHS is less than RHS, so if LHS ever equals RHS then it must be at some $p>n^2$. For $p<n^2$ you always have LHS less than RHS due to monotonicity. But I cannot see how you conclude that $p$ does not necessarily divide $n^3$ from first line?

Comment: @user160738 If $p$ divided $n^3$, it would divide $n$, and thus $p^3 \mid n^7 - n^3$. But $p^3 \nmid p^3 - p$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh right, thanks

Comment: @user160738 Thanks for that.

Comment: If $x \le n^2$ then $x^3 - x \le n^6 - n^2 < n(n^6 - n^2) < n^7-n^3$ so $p > n^2$  If $x \ge n^3$ then $p^3 - p \ge n^9 - n^3 > n^7 - n^3$ so $p < n^3$ so either $p|n^3$ which is impossible as that would mean $p|n$ and $p \le n$, or $p|n^2 + 1$

Answer (score 3):

We have $$p(p+1)(p-1)=n^3(n^2+1)(n+1)(n-1)$$ so, clearly, $n=1$ and $n\ge p$ are discarded hence one has $1\lt n\lt p$ and $(n,p)=1$ and $p$ neither divides $n^3$ nor $n-1$. Besides the possibility $p=n+1$ is easily discarded.

It follows $p$ divides $n^2+1$ and since $n^2+1$ neither divides $p-1$ nor $p+1$ then we get $$p=n^2+1$$
which gives immediately the solution $(p,n)=(5,2)$.

That this solution is the only one is deduced putting the value of $p$ in the given equality so we have

$$n^2(n^2+1)(n^2+2)=n^7-n^3\iff n^5-n^4-3n^3-n-2=0$$ this last equation has as only real root $n=2$ (*the other roots are $\pm i$ and $\pm \sqrt[3]{-1}$*).

Thus $(p,n)=(5,2)$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the case $p\lt n^2$, note that $p\lt n^2$ implies $p+1\lt n^2+1$ and $p-1\lt n^2-1$, and this gives $p^3-p=p(p+1)(p-1)\lt n^2(n^2+1)(n^2-1)\le n^3(n^2+1)(n^2-1)=n^7-n^3$.

Remark:  The paragraph that argues that either $p\gt n^2$ or $p\lt n^2$ isn't really necessary.  It's obvious that $p\not=n^2$, since primes cannot be squares.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $p,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, where $p$ is a prime, such that $p^3-p=n^7-n^3$.

This implies that $p(p^2-1)=n^3(n^2-1)(n^2+1)\implies p|n^3$ or $p|n^2-1$ or $p|n^2+1$.

**Case 1:** $p|n^3$. This implies that $p|n\implies n=pk$ for some positive integer $k$. Therefore we have $n^7=p^7k^7$ and $n^3=p^3k^3$. Therefore $$p^3-p=p^7k^7-p^3k^3\\ \implies p^2-1=p^6k^7-p^2k^3\\\implies p^2-1=p^2(p^4k^7-k^3)\\\implies p^2|p^2-1, \text{ which is a contradiction.}$$ Hence $p\not|n^3.$

**Case 2:** $p|n^2-1.$ Observe that for any prime $p_1, p_1^3-p_1>0\implies p^3-p>0\implies n^7-n^3=n^3(n^2-1)(n^2+1)>0.$ Now for any $n_1\in\mathbb{N}, n_1^3>0$ and $n_1^2+1>0$. This implies that $n^3>0$ and $n^2+1>0$, which in turn implies that we must have $n^2-1>0$.

Therefore, $p|n^2-1$ implies that $pk=n^2-1$, for some positive integer $k$. Therefore, $n^2+1=pk+2$ and $n^3=pkn+n$.

Therefore we have $$p^3-p=n^7-n^3=n^3(n^2-1)(n^2+1)=(pkn+n)(pk)(pk+2)\\\implies p^2-1=(pk^2+2k)(pkn+n).$$

Now $pk^2+2k>p$ and $pkn+n>p$, which in turn implies that $(pk^2+n)(pkn+n)>p^2$. Therefore we have $$p^2-1>p^2\\\implies -1>0, \text{ which is a contradiction.}$$ Hence $p\not |n^2-1.$

**Case 3:** $p|n^2+1$. This implies that $p\le n^2+1$. Now since we have $$p^3-p=n^7-n^3\implies p^3-p=n^3(n^4-1)\implies n^3|p^3-p\implies n^3\le p^3-p\implies n^3<p^3\implies n<p.$$

Therefore we have $n<p\le n^2+1$. Thus $n^2<p^2\le (n^2+1)^2\implies n^2-1< p^2-1\le n^4+2n^2.$

Hence we have $$n^3-n<p^3-p\le (n^2+1)(n^4+2n^2)\\ \implies n^3-n<n^7-n^3\le n^6+3n^4+2n^2\\ \implies n^2-1<n^6-n^2\le n^5+3n^3+2n\hspace{0.5 cm}...(*)$$

Observe that $(*)$ is satisfied only by $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Now of course $n=1$ yields no solution, since $p^3-p>0$.

Now when $n=2$, we have $p^3-p=(p-1)p(p+1)=120.$ Observe that only $p=5$ satisfies the equation.

Therefore, the only pair $(p,n)$ that satisfies the equation $p^3-p=n^7-n^3$ is $(p,n)=(5,2)$.