# Solving Diophantine Equations Involving Primes

Tags: number-theory

Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that $$p^3-q^7=p-q$$

The above equation can be written as $$p^3-p=q^7-q \implies p(p^2-1)=q(q^3-1)(q^3+1),$$ Now if $p$ divides $q$ then $p=q$ giving no solutions

It is easy to see that $p>q$ On the other hand $p\mid q^3-1$ or $p\mid q^3+1$, The former one gives $q^3=kp+1$ for some $k>0$. So we get $$p(p^2-1)=q(kp+2)(kp) \implies p^2-1=k^2pq+2kq \implies p^2-k^2pq-1-2kq=0$$ which is a quadratic in $p$ so the discriminant $k^4q^2+8kq+4$ must be a perfect square but $$(k^2q)^2<k^4q^2+8kq+4<(k^2q+1)^2$$ for $k \geq 4$ so a contradiction.

And if $p\mid q^3+1$ then $q^3=kp-1$, so we get the equation $$p(p^2-1)=q(kp-2)(kp) \implies p^2-1=k^2qp-2kq \implies p^2-k^2qp+2kq-1=0.$$
This is a quadratic in $p$, so the discriminant $k^4q^2-8kq+4$ must be a perfect square, but $$(k^2q-1)^2<k^4q^2-8kq+4<(k^2q)^2$$ for $k \geq 4$, so a contradiction. So we cannot have $k \geq 4$ and putting these values of $k$ i.e. $ k \leq 3$ we can get the values of the primes $p$ and $q$

Is My Proof Correct???

Comment: It's been available everywhere including Aops community, I wish that you use some search results for more exposure on it, other methods are useful too

Comment: Is my method correct or not??

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270675/find-all-primes-p-q-such-that-p3p-q7q?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: I don't need the answer, I olny want to know that is my proof correct?

Comment: There is a small error. The inequality $k^4q^2+8kq+4<(k^2q+1)^2$ does not hold for $k=4$.