# Find all primes $r$ and $s$ such that $ r^7+s=s^3+r $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find all primes $r$ and $s$ such that $\;r^7+s=s^3+r\;.$

I have tried to factorise the expression since we are dealing with primes so:
$$ s(s^2-1)= r(r^6-1)=r(r^2-1)(r^4+r^2+1).$$
Since $ s^3>r^7$, then $\;s^2-1>r^4-1$.

That is all what I have found, thank you in advance for your precious help!

Comment: Might be obvious, but why is $s^3>r^7$ ?

Comment: Because $s^3-r^7 = s - r >0$

Comment: @jjagmath, why $s-r>0$ ? Could you give a more detailed explanation ?

Comment: If we had $s \le r$ then $s^3-s \le r^3-r < r^7-r$. A contradiction.

Comment: But the important part is that intuitively, you can observe the dominant terms: $r^7\approx s^3$, so $s>r$.

Comment: $s\equiv s^3\pmod 7\implies s\equiv \pm 1\pmod 7$

Comment: $13^3+3=3^7+13=2200$.

Comment: With similar reason to my above comment if $3\not\mid r\implies s\equiv s^3\pmod 9\implies s\equiv \pm 1\pmod 9$

Comment: See also this very similar post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270675/find-all-primes-p-q-such-that-p3p-q7q/2277048). Perhaps it is also useful here.

Answer (score 7):

Factoring $r^6 - 1$ using the difference of squares, and then factoring each of those parts, gives

$$s(s^2 - 1) = r(r^6 - 1) = r(r^3 - 1)(r^3 + 1) = r(r - 1)(r^2 + r + 1)(r + 1)(r^2 - r + 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $r \neq s$, the left side of \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$r \mid s^2 - 1 = (s - 1)(s + 1) \; \; \to \; \; (r \mid s - 1) \; \lor \; (r \mid s + 1) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This means there's a positive integer $k$ such that

$$s = kr \pm 1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $s \gt r + 1$ (as $r \neq 2$), then using the left and right sides factorization in \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$(s \mid r^2 + r + 1) \; \lor \; (s \mid r^2 - r + 1) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

For the first one, this means there's an integer $1 \le m \le r$ where, using \eqref{eq3A}, we get

$$r^2 + r + 1 = ms = m(kr \pm 1) = kmr \pm m \; \to \; r^2 + (1 - km)r + (1 \mp m) = 0 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

Thus, $1 \mp m$ must be a multiple of $r$. Due to the limits on $m$, it must be either $0$, so $m = 1$, or $r$, so $m = r - 1$. For the latter case, \eqref{eq5A} becomes

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
& r^2 + (1 - k(r - 1))r + r = 0 \\
& r^2 + r - k(r - 1)r + r = 0 \\
& r - k(r - 1) = -2 \\
& (1 - k)r = -(2 + k) \\
& (k - 1)r = k + 2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Note $k = 1$ is not a solution, and $k = 2$ gives $r = 4$ which is not prime. With $k \gt 2 \; \to \; k - 1 \gt 1$, note \eqref{eq6A} gives $k - 1 \mid k + 2$. Also, $\gcd(k - 1, k + 2) = \gcd(k - 1, (k + 2) - (k - 1)) = d$ means $d = 1$ or $d = 3$. Thus, $k - 1 = 3$, so $k = 4$ and \eqref{eq6A} gives $3r = 6 \; \to \; r = 2$. However, $r = 2$ is not a possible solution. Thus, this means $m = 1$, i.e., the left side of \eqref{eq5A} becomes

$$r^2 + r + 1 = s \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

This then gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
0 & = r^7 - r + s - s^3 \\
& = r^7 - r + (r^2 + r + 1) - (r^2 + (r + 1))^3 \\
& = r^7 + r^2 + 1 - r^6 - 3(r^4)(r + 1) - 3(r^2)(r + 1)^2 - (r + 1)^3 \\
& = r^7 + r^2 + 1 - r^6 - 3r^5 - 6r^4 - 7r^3 - 6r^2 - 3r - 1 \\
& = r^7 - r^6 - 3r^5 - 6r^4 - 7r^3 - 5r^2 - 3r \\
& = r(r^6 - r^5 - 3r^4 - 6r^3 - 7r^2 - 5r - 3)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Dividing both sides by $r$ gives $r^6 - r^5 - 3r^4 - 6r^3 - 7r^2 - 5r - 3 = 0$, but since $r$ must divide this left side, this means $r \mid 3$, so $r = 3$. This gives $0$ in \eqref{eq8A}, with $s = 13$ from \eqref{eq7A}. Checking the original equation, as [Oscar Lanzi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/248217/oscar-lanzi)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222576/find-all-primes-r-and-s-such-that-r7s-s3r#comment8768111_4222576) indicates, gives $3^7 + 13 = 13^3 + 3 = 2200$.

Using a similar argument to the above for the second part of \eqref{eq4A} leads to

$$r^2 - r + 1 = s \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

This results in

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
0 & = r^7 - r + s - s^3 \\
& = r^7 - r + (r^2 - r + 1) - (r^2 - (r - 1))^3 \\
& = r^7 + r^2 - 2r + 1 - r^6 + 3(r^4)(r - 1) - 3(r^2)(r - 1)^2 + (r - 1)^3 \\
& = r^7 + r^2 - 2r + 1 - r^6 + 3r^5 - 6r^4 + 7r^3 - 6r^2 + 3r - 1 \\
& = r^7 - r^6 + 3r^5 - 6r^4 + 7r^3 - 5r^2 + r \\
& = r(r^6 - r^5 + 3r^4 - 6r^3 + 7r^2 - 5r + 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

This leads to $r \mid 1 \; \to \; r = 1$, which is not allowed (however, it does satisfy \eqref{eq10A} and gives $s = 1$ in \eqref{eq9A}, with this being a solution of $r^7 + s = s^3 + r$), so there are no valid solutions in this case.

In conclusion, the only solution in primes $r$ and $s$ is $r = 3$ and $s = 13$.

Answer (score 6):

Trying to milk more out of the factorization
$$
s(s-1)(s+1)=s^3-s=r^7-r=r(r-1)(r+1)(r^2-r+1)(r^2+r+1).\qquad(*)
$$

The OP already observed that $s^3>r^7$. Therefore $s>r^2$. Let's remember that $s$ is a prime. Staring at $(*)$ for a few seconds tells us that the only possible prime factor of the RHS larger than $r^2$ is $r^2+r+1$.

> Therefore we must have $s=r^2+r+1$.

Plugging this into $(*)$ gives us
$$
\begin{aligned}0&=r^7-r-(r^2+r+1)^3+(r^2+r+1)\\
&=r(r+1)(r-3)(r^2+1)(r^2+r+1).
\end{aligned}
$$

Obviously $r=3$ is the only relevant solution and, luckily, $s=r^2+r+1=13$ turns out to be a prime.

Comment: In a sense this combines the attacks of the other two answers. Use the factorization like John and the size estimates like Mike. +1 to all.

Comment: Nice! This does have a new idea, I'd have one check $r=3,5,7,11,13$. But this answer observes straightaway that all it could possibly be is $r=3$.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo @Oscar.

Comment: If one only wants $r,s$ positive integers, not required to be primes, does anyone know some other examples than $3,13$?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a full-fledged answer yet but it is too long for a comment: On the one hand,

$$r|(s^2-1) \Rightarrow s=kr \pm 1$$ $$\Rightarrow s \equiv_r \pm 1.$$

On the other hand, $s \in \theta(r^{\frac{7}{3}})$ and $s$ divides one of $r^3-1$, $r^3+1$ gives $as = r^3\pm 1$ for some $a \in O(r^{3-\frac{7}{3}}) =O(r^{\frac{2}{3}})$.
But $as \equiv_r \pm a$ because $s \equiv_r \pm 1$, so either $a=1$ [which is impossible] or $a \ge r-1$. But both $a \in O(r^{\frac{2}{3}})$ and $a\ge r-1$ is impossible for $r$ sufficiently large. So the solution set is bounded.

ETA: You could also use the fact that both $r^3-1$ and $r^3+1$ factor further to polynomials no larger than $r^2+r+1$ [as noted in @John Omielan 's answer below, I had forgotten this], to conclude that $s \le r^2+r+1$, because $r,s$ prime $\Rightarrow$ $s$ must divide one of $r^2+r+1$, $r^2-r+1$, $r-1$, $r+1$. Then this gives $r^7-r \le (r^2+r+1)^3-(r^2+r+1)$ [because $y^3-y$ is strictly increasing in $y$ for $y \ge 3$]. All solutions for $r^7-r \le (r^2+r+1)^3-(r^2+r+1)$ require $r \le 13$. This leaves very few possibilities to check, check the value of $s$ that satisfies $s^3-s=r^7-r$ for each $r \in \{3,5,7,11,13\}$.

Comment: Interesting. If we can quantify thus bound, we can run trials. Any identified bound must allow a solution $(r,s)=(3,13)$.

Comment: You could also use the fact that both $r^3-1$ and $r^3+1$ factor further to polynomials no larger than $r^2+r+1$ [as noted in @John Omielan 's answer, I had forgotten this], to conclude that $s \le r^2+r+1$. Then this gives $r^-7-r \ge (r^2+r+1)^3-(r^2+r+1)$ [because $y^3-y$ is strictly increasing in $y$ for $y \ge 3$]. All solutions for $r^-7-r \ge (r^2+r+1)^3-(r^2+r+1)$ require $r \le 13$. This leaves very few choices.

Comment: "Then this gives $r^7−r≥(r^2+r+1)^3−(r^2+r+1)$ ...". $\le$ maybe?

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the obvious typo that Oscar spotted.